# Изменение ключа localstorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Можно ли изменить имя ключа (не значение) в localstorage не прибегая к удалению и вставки нового имени?
Так не получается:
localStorage.key('1') = '2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, перед вставкой удалять не обязательно. Достаточно установить новое значение

```
localStorage['key'] = 'oldval';
localStorage['key'] = 'newval';
```

в итоге по ключу `key` будет значение 'newval'

Также для вставки значения можно использовать функцию [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

```
storage.setItem(названиеКлюча, значениеКлюча);
```

[Функция key](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage/key) возвращает название ключа, а не значение, по ключу.

Comment: Мне нужно поменять сам ключ - т.е. название ключа, а не значение ключа (value)

Comment: @Nik, изменять сам ключ - нельзя. Так как операция не имеет смысла

Comment: У меня специфичный подход видимо)

Comment: @Nik, пока просто непонятно _зачем_. Возможно настоящая проблема в чем-то другом

Answer (score 0):

Это не правильный подход и в таких вещах нет необходимости.

Тем не менее, вы можете взять `localStore` клиента.
К примеру у нас есть `localStore` с данными `localStore['user'] = 'admin'`.
Мы можем прочитать `localStore` на сервере, запомнить, а после удалить `localSotre['admin']` и запушить новый `localStore` с новыми ключом (к примеру `username`) и старыми данными, в итоге получим `localStore['username'] = 'admin`